# Excel : Simple example but Excel Solver can't find feasible solution

Tags: excel, excel-solver

I want to make a travel plan using Excel Solver to decide which city to visit in order and how long to stay.
I'm going to leave from city A and come back to city A.

Below table shows the airfare for moving from one city to another, and the cost of accommodation per day for staying in each city.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZR2q.png)

Target(Blue cell): To minimize Total expense (N17)
Cells to change(Green cells): Staying days in a city ($D$17:$F$19)

For example, 9 in F17 cell means moving from A to C and staying in C for 9 days.
'From count'(Column H) checks the number of departures from each city
=COUNTIF(D18:G18,">0")

'To count'(Row 22) checks number of times you arrive in each city
=COUNTIF(D18:D21,">0")

'necessary?'(Column K) checks if you have ever arrived in the city (because if you have arrived, you also have to leave)
=HLOOKUP(C19,$D$17:$G$22,6,FALSE)

'Total Airfair' (Column M) calculates total airfair
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(D5:G5,D18:G18)/SUM(D18:G18), 0)

'Total Accom. Cost' (Column N) calculates total accommodation cost
=SUMPRODUCT($D$13:$G$13,D18:G18)

Constraints include following

- We're not moving to the same city

> D18 = 0
> E19 = 0
> F20 = 0
> G21 = 0

- Number of staying should be an integer
  D18:G21 = integer
- travel starts from city A
  H18 = 1
- come back to city A
  D22 = 1
- We're not going to stop by a city more than once

> H19:H21 <= 1
> E22:G22 <= 1

- if you have arrived in a city, you also have to leave

> H19:H21 >= K19:K21

- Total staying days (except to come back to A and stay) should be 10

> D26 = sum(E18:G21) = 10

- Total visiting cities (except A) should be 2

> D27 = sum(E22:G22) = 2

- Number of days to return to A and stay at A is randomly specified as 1

> D19:D21 <= 1

I'd like to use this logic in five city examples, but Excel can't find a feasible solution even in this toy example.

What's the reason and how can I make it work?

*I just found that I can't attach the excel file. Is it possible to attach here? I can send you by email if you want.

I think the number shown on the captured image would be the best travel plan. If I enter this number and run solver, I find a solution, but if I clear all the numbers and run it, I don't find a solution.

*I heard that solver does not recognize countif function, so I tried to use iferror, for example, in cell H18
=IFERROR(D18/D18, 0)+IFERROR(E18/E18, 0)+IFERROR(F18/F18, 0)+IFERROR(G18/G18, 0)
instead of countif, but I also couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, came up with this, but you will need to think about what to improve:

[image]

I did not use binary as the from count is held to 1.

Note you get 7 days in city C as it is the cheapest... So add a constraint that duration cells D22:F22 must be >=2... for a minumum 2 day stay.